# time complexitiy of hashmap

Tags: java, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of iterating a hash map in average case? I think its `O(n)`

What is the time complexity of `map.get(key);` I think its `O(1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), which should be your first port of call:

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets. Iteration over collection views requires time proportional to the "capacity" of the HashMap instance (the number of buckets) plus its size (the number of key-value mappings). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is important.

Comment: @Jon: you must have the API on hotkey or something... :)

Comment: @jon :I made some chnages in original post, can you comment?

Comment: @jslearner: Yes - you've got them round the wrong way. How can iterating a hash map be O(1)?

Comment: @jslearner if you iterate through the keys then you it will be o(1) for retrieval of value for each key, and [yes you are right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580668/time-complexitiy-of-hashmap/5580678#5580678)

Comment: @jon>sorry i made mistake while typing, i corrected it now, is it correct now?

Comment: @jslearner: read the quotation again ;) assuming that that hashing function works properly and the capacity, loadFactor parameters are set properly for your particular case, get(key) should take constant time, not linear.

Comment: @jslearner: Well, assuming your capacity is O(n) as well, yes.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Can I run 5000 map insertion operation at a time? would it take too much space?

Comment: @typedef: We don't know what counts as "too much" - but a map with 5000 entries is fine, and reasonably small even, certainly for server-side work.

Answer (score 2):

`O(1)` which is constant in normal case, *if they don't collide*

**See Also**

- [HashMap API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
- [HashTable Data Structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Answer (score 1):

From the [API:](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets. Iteration over collection views requires time proportional to the "capacity" of the HashMap instance (the number of buckets) plus its size (the number of key-value mappings). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is important.